# Solvable product $HN$

Tags: group-theory

I have this following exercise: Let $G$ be a finite group. $N\trianglelefteq G$ and $H\subseteq G$ be solvable. Show that $HN$ is solvable.

For the proof we need 2 things:

1. $G/N$ solvable and $N$ solvable $\Leftrightarrow$ $G$ solvable.
2. $HN/N\cong H/(H\cap N)$

Then it basically finishes itself.

> Question: It seems to me that $G$ being finite is a needless requirement. Is that correct?

EDIT (proof): Since $H$ is solvable, we have that $H/(H\cap N)$ is solvable (by 1.). Then $HN/N$ is solvable (by 2.) and since $N$ is solvable we have $HN$ is solvable (again by 1.).

Comment: What is $N$? If $N=G$ then $HN=G$ and thus this won't be true even when $G$ is finite.

Comment: I edited it: $N\trianglelefteq G$.

Comment: Yeah, that still fails for $N=G$. Or do you assume that $N$ is solvable as well?

Comment: Maybe my syntax is bad. $N$ is solvable.

Comment: OK, so how about you show us your proof and we'll verify if finitness is a necessary assumption (probably not)?

Comment: Alright, edited it again.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right. I think you are correct, finitness is not necessary.

Comment: @DonAntonio Typo.